# mysql where condition not working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, web

I have written my php code in codeigniter but when I set $limit = 1, still i get records that have seen = 1 why??
i have written a mysql query in pure sql but the problem remains !
here is my code :

```
function getComment($limit)
{
    while( !$this->checkFuncState('getComment') );
    $this->lockFunc('getComment');
    $grade = $this->session->userdata('grade');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->select('m_comments.id AS `ComId`');
    $this->db->select('m_comments.approved AS `Comappr`');
    $this->db->select('m_comments.content AS `ComContent`');
    $this->db->select('m_users.hid AS `UserHid`');
    $this->db->from('m_comments');
    $this->db->join('m_users','m_comments.user_id = m_users.id');
    if( $grade == "0" || $grade == "1" )
        $this->db->where("( m_comments.approved = 0 || m_comments.approved = -15 )");
    else
        $this->db->where('m_comments.approved','0');
    $this->db->where('m_comments.seen','0');
    $this->db->limit($limit);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    $this->setComsSeen($q);
    $this->unlockFunc('getComment');
    return $q;
}
```

Comment: hi and welcome to SO. Sorry but can you explain your problem again? I dont understand "...still i get records that have seen = 1 why..." Thanks

Comment: what is your function `$this->checkFuncState('getComment')` does?

Comment: in where clauses i have write the condition "Where seen = 0" but i get recordes that their seen is 1 :(

Comment: the function checkFuncState and lockFunc and unlockFunc are locking function for mutual exclusion my problem is that where condition("Where seen = 0" is not working :(

Comment: How do you check that result has **seen=1** records? could you show proof `$q = $this->db->get(); var_dump($q);` the output of var_dump if do right after result is received?

Comment: Your question is confused. Are you having issues with the limit function or the where? You have hard coded your where condition to seen=0. Limit doesnt have anything to do with this it just reduces the number of returned rows to the limit